# ListBookmarks does not output any features

Tags: arcpy, bookmarks, arcgis-10.4

I'm trying to use [ListBookmarks](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listbookmarks.htm) in Python to output my bookmarks to features. I directly copied the code in the sample provided. It "succeeds" and creates the feature class I wanted, but it is empty with no features. Did anybody have the same problem and solve it? Using ArcMap 10.4, Python 2.7.10, and Windows 8.1.

Here's the code I used, but it's essentially the same as the sample:

```
import arcpy, os

# The map with the bookmarks
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\GIS\Projects\ACE\Easement Maps\UtilityOutgrants2.mxd")

# The output feature class to be created -
# This feature class will store the bookmarks as features
outFC = r'D:\Default.gdb\Bookmarks'

# A template feature class that contains the attribute schema
# Including a "Name" field to store the bookmark name
template = r'D:\Default.gdb\Template'

if arcpy.Exists(outFC):
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFC)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outFC),
                                    os.path.basename(outFC), 
                                    "POLYGON", template, 
                                    spatial_reference=template)

cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC, ["SHAPE@", "Name"])
array = arcpy.Array()
for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, "Layers"):
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMax))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMax))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    # To close the polygon, add the first point again
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    cur.insertRow([arcpy.Polygon(array), bkmk.name])
    array.removeAll()

print "done"
```

Comment: I've never had a problem doing this but something to double-check is that your MXD has been saved with those bookmarks in it.  Also, I don't think I ever use a template feature class so perhaps try running this without that as a test.

Comment: Thanks, I double-checked. Bookmarks are saved and I ran it without the template. Same result. One thing to note is that schema locks seem to have retained after code was finished executing. I don't know if that is important, but it makes me want to believe that it is still trying to create the features...

Comment: Make sure to delete the cursor at the end of your code. `del cur`

Comment: I think the presence of those schema locks may be highly relevant.  I recommend closing ArcMap, closing your Python script and IDE, then re-opening them and trying again.  I think you'll find it works then.

Comment: Very strange, I use slightly modified version of this script (thank you @PolyGeo) all the time. Tried to kill it using different extents in mxd, it still works

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `DataFrame` object in the `ListBookmarks()` function, as specified in the [function documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listbookmarks.htm)? You can get this easily from the `mxd` object: `for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, "Layers", mxd.activeDataFrame)`

Comment: @dmahr has made an excellent suggestion - we often think of bookmarks being MXD-wide when they are actually tied to a data frame.

Comment: Thank you @dmahr and PolyGeo, I went ahead and used mxd.activeDataFrame (my active layer name is "Layers") and closing everything - Python, IDE, ArcMap - also added del cur to kill the locks. Double-checked that no locks were there and executed, but I'm still getting the same result. So I tried to use this on another mxd I created and then on another users computer to try to isolate the problem, but same result on both instances. This is killing me!

Comment: @Kwan I think you need to separate your task into the two parts: 1) parsing the points from the bookmarks, and 2) using the `insertCursor` to output polygons. Double check that 1) is being done correctly by printing the coordinates within the for loop with `arcpy.AddMessage(bkmk.extent.JSON)`. If the coordinates are correct, then something is wrong with 2) your use of the cursor. Perhaps you need to specify the `spatial_reference` within your `arcpy.Polygon()` constructor?

Comment: Thank you all. After trying it on different MXDs and slight modifications to inputs, I was able to get this to work finally. I'm not sure exactly what the issue was. In fact, my final code looks exactly like the sample from ArcGIS support. Now I'm wondering how to best "close" this question since I don't really have an answer other than remain persistent.